# How do I insert a text from variable at the certain line of a text file?

Tags: command-line, sed

I want to insert a text from variable at the certain line of a text file.

```
$cat foo
hello
hello
$var=`cat foo`
$echo "$var"
hello
$cat bar
some
text
```

I want to insert $var into second line, but sed does not read the content of the variable:

```
sed -i -e '2i$var\' bar
hello
$var
world
```

I guess because of two identical words in foo, I'm getting this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: extra characters after command
```

Comment: A better way to do that IMHO would be to use the `r` command, with its input from `/dev/stdin` e.g. `sed '1r /dev/stdin' bar <<< "$var"`. That way, there's no danger of the contents of `$var` being treated as part of an expression. Of course in your example (where `$var` consists of the contents of file `foo`), you can skip the variable altogether and just do `sed '1r foo' bar`

Comment: @steeldriver Great, exactly what I was looking for! ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You call variables in sed with double quotes

```
sed -i -e "2i$var" bar
```

Comment: I guess the slash was one of the problem

Comment: @JosefKlimuk: There are two problems in the example of the question: `sed -i -e '2i$var\' bar`. The first problem are the single quotes - inside them them the character `$` doesn't have special meaning. The second is the backslash, indeed - it escapes the special meaning of the second single quote mark.

Comment: @pa4080 Thanks. And what about my $var is two identical strings? It also gives out a problem, look in my edited question.